# How to calculate Multiple Regression in Oracle

Tags: oracle, regression, linear-regression

In Oracle there is an inbuilt function Regr_ to calculate linear regression.Can someone advice if there is any function to find multiple regression in oracle ? I want to find one dependent variable using regression with Multiple independent variables.

Comment: The Oracle docs at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57185_01/CBPUG/ch03s04s03.html say for step 1: "On the Predictor wizard Methods panel, select Multiple Linear Regression.", and http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_callan_using_sql_part1.htm has discussion if regr_ for multiple regression.

Comment: @JamesPhillips - the first link is to the documentation for Predictor, which is part of Oracle's Hyperion suite, a **completely separate product** from the RDBMS and so rather unhelpful as a hint. The Steve Callan article is almost fifteen years old, but at least it's about actual Oracle SQL, so that's something.

Comment: Have a look at the UTL_NLA package. [Oracle 12c docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_nla.htm). The Datawarehousing guide has an example of implementing Linear Algebra which you may find useful. [Check it out](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E25554_01/analysis.htm#BCFEFEBD)